# Is it possible to evaluate confidence score from accuracy of an NVIDIA NeMo Text Classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, artificial-intelligence, text-classification

Is it possible to calculate the Confidence score while predicting the class labels from the NVIDIA NeMo Text Classification model?

I have attached the script for predicting the accuracy of the Nemo Text Classification model for reference.

```
# Test the model
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for i, batch in enumerate(validation_dataloader):
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        # Unpack the inputs from our dataloader
        b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch
        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask)
        # print (outputs)
        prediction = torch.argmax(outputs[0],dim=1)
        total += b_labels.size(0)
        correct+=(prediction==b_labels).sum().item()

print('Test Accuracy of the model on the data is: {} %'.format(100 * correct / total))
```

Comment: What do you mean by confidence? In general accuracy represents the confidence of the model: accuracy = 90% means that the model is correct 90% of the time.

Comment: During the inferencing phase, the task requires predicting the class labels along with the confidence score dedicated to each class.

Comment: I assume that you call 'confidence' the probability of each class for a given instance. You have these probabilities in `outputs` for every instance (you might have to apply softmax on the array, I'm not sure), but since you currently apply `argmax` on the array this gives you only the predicted label for instance (the one with  maximum prob). The accuracy is calculated on the labels globally, not on every instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did apply the Softmax() function on the legits generated immediately in the definition of Nemo toolkit's classifytext() function in its Text Classification section.